# Base64 encoding can't be inserted into mongodb

Tags: playframework, morphia

The text field in Notification stores the base64 encoded image data.However, it works when the image is small e.g. 30k. But if the image is big like 150k, the Notification class will get inserted into mongodb without the text field.

```
@Entity(value = "notification", noClassnameStored = true)
public class Notification {
    @Id
    public ObjectId id = new ObjectId();
    public ObjectId uid = new ObjectId();
    public String name;
    public String text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to initialize the `id`, this will be done automatically by the database. I'm not sure why you would want to add a second `ObjectId`.
2. Are you sure the base64 encoding is working correctly? I've experimented with multi megabyte strings in MongoDB and I've never had any problems with it.
   Maybe you can show the part where you are base64 encoding the binary?
3. Are you sure this is the best approach for storing binary data? I'd think that GridFS or some similar technology would be more efficient.

Comment: [1].If i want to associate with 2 documents for example student and course(student study multiple courses) with each having an Id. What is the best approach to do that? If i use reference e.g. reference , will it load the courses every time i load a student. Or is there anything like lazy loading in Morphia?

[2].I use a base64 image encoding plugin for CKEDITOR. I dont have the code how it encodes the image but when i print it out, it looks correct. And it works with small size of images.

[3].The reason is i want to embed the image to the HTML template so they are in the same place.

Comment: you can add the parameter lazy to a reference. can you debug if you are handing over to morphia? as i've said, really long strings have been working fine for us...